# ActiveRecord Reputation System gem with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to use [Twitter's ActiveRecord Reputation System gem](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/) with a `Rails 4` application

Ive added `gem 'activerecord-reputation-system'` to my `Gemfile` and have run `bundle install`

When I run `rails generate reputation_system` I get the following error:

```
/Users/Dee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.2/lib/active_model/deprecated_mass_assignment_security.rb:14:in `attr_accessible': `attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one. (RuntimeError)
```

Ive tried adding `gem 'protected_attributes'` to my `Gemfile` but that didn't fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', github: 'NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system', branch: 'rails4'
```

in my `Gemfile` solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

The official `activerecord-reputation-system` gem now supports Rails 4 (since version 3.0).